# webdrivermanager TypeError

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Trying to use webdrivermanager for selenium

I am using python version 2.7.13.

I am running a backing setup for setting up webdriver as explained in the docs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

As far as I know it says that this package does work for python 2. But I get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

I am thinking this is the difference between Python 2 and 3, but I have seen people running this package on Python 2...

I have tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(ChromeDriverManager, self).install())
```

But it says self is not defined?!

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver manager supports the only python version >=3.6